# Access data from API

Tags: javascript

This might be a silly question but I can't seem to find a solution.
I have the following data from an API I'm trying to access.
This is a screenshot from the `console.log`.

[image]

I can easily get `category`, `content`, `content.content` etc. and so on,
but I'm trying to get the `OBS_VALUE` and `SEX` and don't know how to get it.

I would usually do:

`data.cross:DataSet.cross:Section.cross:Obs.[i].OBS_VALUE`

But doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: It's `data['cross:DataSet']['cross:Section']['cross:Obs'][i].OBS_VALUE`

Comment: Hey guys, many thanks for your answers. I'm realising this is a bigger task that I imagined. Would anyone be willing to give me a more in depth hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = {
"cross:Dataset":{"cross:Section":{"cross:Obs":[{"OBS_STATUS":"A","OBS_VALUE":22677,"SEX":"M"}]}}
}
console.log(result["cross:Dataset"]["cross:Section"]["cross:Obs"][0].OBS_VALUE)
```

Comment: Hey guys, many thanks for your answers. I'm realising this is a bigger task that I imagined. Would anyone be willing to give me a more in depth hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a test array of data that can help you understand the main concept.

```
const data = [
  {
    cross: [
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test1" },
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test2" },
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test3" },
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test4" }
    ]
  },
  {
    cross: [
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test1" },
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test2" },
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test3" },
      { obsStatus: "1", obsValue: "test4" }
    ]
  }
];
```

how i use it:

1. if i want to map the data its sth like this:

```
{data.map((item) => {
        return item.cross.map((items) => {
          return <p>{items.obsValue}</p>;
        });
})}
```

2. if i want to use special index:

```
{data[0].cross[0].obsValue}
```

Comment: This is not what she asked for.

Comment: Hey guys, many thanks for your answers. I'm realising this is a bigger task that I imagined. Would anyone be willing to give me a more in depth hand? Thanks!